# XUnit run code after all [Theory] tests have completed

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, xunit.net

Imagine I have a set of properties I want to test.

```
class MyClass
{
   public int Value1 {get;set;}
   public string Value2 {get;set;}
   public float Value3 {get;set;}
}
```

I want to test each property:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(nameof(MyClass.Value1))]
[InlineData(nameof(MyClass.Value2))]
public void CheckValue(string propertyName)
{
 ...
}
```

You can see I've forgotten to test `Value3`.  So I create a test fixture, to capture all the names of MyClass at the start.  Now, in the fixture `Dispose()` I can make sure that every property has a CheckValue test, and log an error if not.

The fixture checks run after ALL the tests in my test class, but then the error messages generated are attached to ALL failing tests, not just the ones the test relates to.

*Is there a way to run some code after all the tests in a [Theory] have run?*

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `InlineData` you could use `MemberData` and use reflection to make absolutely sure you return all the properties. It would look like this:

```
        [Theory]
        [MemberData(nameof(MyPropertyNames))]
        public void CheckValue(string propertyName)
        {
            Assert.True(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName));
        }

        public static IEnumerable<object[]> MyPropertyNames()
        {
            Type myType = typeof(MyClass);
            foreach (PropertyInfo info in myType.GetProperties())
            {
                yield return new object[] { info.Name };
            }
        }
```

This is not running code after the Theory, but it accomplishes what you really want.